# Uninstall preinstalled “Word” app

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps

I have Windows 10 Mobile and need to uninstall preinstalled Word application.

Can we do that, if yes how?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to All applications list.
2. Find "Word" icon and long press on it.
3. You'll get to menu with two options either to pin to Start menu or uninstall.
4. Choose Uninstall.

I talking here about latest final-public build. I don't know if it's possible on older builds.

Answer (score 2):

The [method](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13848/18061) said by @[mms911](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/17729/mms911) is the shortest way. But there is an another way,

1. Open Settings app.
2. Go to *System->Storage*.
3. Choose *This device* or *SD Card*.
4. Select *Apps & Games*.
5. Click on **Word** on app list.
6. Click *Uninstall*.

[image]